# Getting "path" info from the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

**Update: i actually have a pretty good reason. I have a notify class that sends out links to users. So i need to have the URL information in there, simply for the very same routing reasons as the front end ;)

how do i get "path" routes when i am in the model?

```
users_path(xxx)
app.users_path(xxx)
```

Both of this fails

Comment: I think a better question is, why do you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I do agree that in most cases, this should be avoided and there's often a better way of doing it, it's quite short sighted to say that it's *never* needed. In fact, there's a number of circumstances where I would say this is perfectly acceptable (for example, generating csv reports which need to have a link to the object's page on the site).

In any case, Rails makes this quite easy to do. Just make sure you've thought through whether it is appropriate to do first! Just include Rails url helpers in your class...

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: wouldn't generating a csv be a controller/view related action, similar to xml, it doesn't have to be in a  model method.

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends what you're using it for. Sometimes it's more appropriate to generate things in a model or a completely separate class. Say you wanted to generate a csv file which gets emailed daily to a bunch of people... are you saying the best way to generate it would be to create a view, call the view and save it to a file just so you can attach it? No. That's why Rails makes it easy to include the url helpers outside of action controller.

Comment: I am not negating what you are saying. I am just saying its usually a very bad idea, to do that in a model. Basically it kind of butts into the whole concept of MVC, from what I have seen most of these problems are avoided using views helper. In this case, we don't even have enough information to say it should be done or shouldn't be.. :)

Comment: updated with the reason why =)  I am happy to hear of alternative solutions actually. Did not expect such a heated debate on this ;)

Comment: @rishav, I completely agree that it's not normally the best option, which is why I said so in both my original answer and the follow-up comment. I just got frustrated with the unnecessary down-vote when my answer gave OP exactly what he wanted and explained why it isn't normally a good idea but there are exceptions.

Comment: @idlefingers, thanks a lot for the answer. i am using pony (vs actionmailers) to simplify the email notifications, so i need the url for a specific purpose. thanks!

Comment: i am getting a lot of errors here : one of the things that was specified was that it required the default_url_options

Comment: @ming-yeow, you should probably open a new question for those problems.

Answer (score 3):

Thats a bad idea, you shouldn't have to requires routes information inside a model.

If you do, there is definitely something wrong, try and use helpers instead of stuff inside the model.

Or you could provide some more details about the problem and We could provide a definite answer.

**Update** - Assuming, you are sending out emails to your users, you can directly use url helpers in your mailer views ( instead of doing in the model ) . Just remember to use **user_url(xxx)** instead of **user_path(xxx)**. For this you may have also have to set the action_mailer.default_url_options[:host].

Comment: not really, i am using pony. so i am going to stick with idlefinger's suggestion